# Multiple Exception in ItemWriter using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to process staging table data which has 100k records to 5 different core tables without any duplicate data.

For each row I need to validate all columns (30 columns) with some master tables and insert into core tables if record is valid.
For invalid records I need to update errors in staging table itself and skip the row for core table insertion.

Handling entire logic in single step using jpa is running forever. So I divided my job into 7 multithreaded steps

1. DataValidationStep
2. DuplicateCheckTasklet (Within staging table and core table also)
3. Table1Step
4. Table2Step
5. Table3Step
6. Table4Step
7. Table5Step

In this scenario it is taking 40 mins time to complete the job. However some times I am getting multiple errors randomly
like PessimisticLockException, PessimisticLockingFailureException , ConstraintViolationException  and job getting failed.

I am getting ConstraintViolationException when existsByColumn method is fired. Sample code as below in ItemWriter.

```
for(Product product :items){
    if (productRepository.existsByUserIdAndProductId(userId, productId))
    {
        ...
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

I suspect these exceptions are happening because of using JPA.

Also I am using different transactionManager than the one created by Spring batch

Comment: Instead of a multi-threaded step, can you try partitioning?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/scalability.html#partitioning

Comment: @phoenixSid any specific reason?

Comment: I would advise to use measurements that are also understood outside India. If you use Indian words like "lakh", people elsewhere aren't going to know what are "lakh records".